# How Should a REST API Written in Node Consume Blob or File Posted via Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to consume a File posted via the fetch API by my javascript client.  The code to post the File is

```
fetch(URL + `?userId=${userId}`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: file,
                    mode: 'cors',
})
```

However, after that I am pretty much stuck.  I've confirmed that the data arrives at the server; the initial portion of a console log of the request body looks like this

```
'�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0003�\u0000\u0000\u0001[\b\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000q�T$\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0019tEXtSoftware\u0000Adobe ImageReadyq�e<\u0000\u0000\u0004\niTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.0-c060 61.134777, 2010/02/12-17:32:00 "> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:stRef="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmpMM:OriginalDocumentID="uuid:5D20892493BFDB11914A8590D31508C8" xmpMM:DocumentID="xmp.did:2F839FC615A411E59862C6F48B7A3782" xmpMM:InstanceID="xmp.iid:53BEB19215A311E59862C6F48B7A3782" xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (Macintosh)"> <xmpMM:DerivedFrom stRef:instanceID="xmp.iid:c05de654-a6ec-48fe-a042-605a15ba7cb1" stRef:documentID="adobe:docid:photoshop:83a9cc7e-5f57-1178-84a4-89d29074af5a"/> <dc:title> <rdf:Alt> <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">_BeforeAfter</rdf:li> </rdf:Alt> </dc:title> </rdf:Description> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta> <?xpacket end="r"?>\u001bO/ \u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000PLTE>`����Ff�k��x�������悔�Hf�Bd���ޯ�����=^�Gh�������������a{�Un�Hh���
```

The body ends with this:

```
\u001c\u001c\u0017�F����D����D����D����D���D����D����D����D����D����D����D����D���D����D����D����D����D����D����D���(\b�O�\u0001\u0000�|���!v$\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�',isBase64Encoded: false }
```

What kind of encoding am I looking at, and is there a way for Node to convert it back to a blob or file object for use with the putObject method of the AWS S3 SDK?

Comment: You can use `multer` to receive file uploaded by client.

Comment: I've come across busboy and am now trying to send the image file as multipart/form-data.  I chose busboy because my consumer is an AWS lambda function which means I don't have access to the middleware layer that express exposes.  I'm still trying to figure out how to consume the FileStream that busboy makes so that I can write it to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct character encoding too. ASCII won't work with UTF8 characters.

Comment: I checked on the server, and busboy states that the encoding is 7bit which matches up with ASCII encoding.  My question is, how does a javascript File object which points to a PNG file get encoded into ASCII?  Why can't I just get a binary from a File object and then post it?